How to convert list[int, int, int] to tuple[int, int, int] and not tuple[int, ...]
Suppose I have 2 functions, func1 and func2. func1 returns a list of 3 integers, and func2 takes a tuple of 3 integers, how would I convert the list to a tuple in such a way that I can prevent errors by type checkers (I am using mypy).
Here is the code that is throwing error:
var1: list[int, int, int] = func1()
func2(tuple(var1))

Error thrown at func2 call:
Expected type 'tuple[int, int, int]', got 'tuple[int, ...]' instead.

this list[int, int, int] doesn't exists, at a list is supposed to contain ONE type only, it should be list[int]. you can always cast

How exactly can I use casting here? You mean something like:
typing.cast(tuple[int, int, int], var1) after casting var1 to a tuple?

List types do not contain information about their length. (list[int, int, int] is not a list of length 3; mypy doesn't even accept it.) Ideally, mypy could examine a hard-coded slice object to infer that tuple(var1[:2]]) has type tuple[int, int, int], but that is not the case (at least, today).
In the mean time, you can construct the tuple explicitly:
func2((var1[0], var1[1], var1[2]))


Thank you, this seems like the only way. list[int, int, int] was a silly mistake on my part.

You could use cast, but I prefer to avoid lying to the type checker whenever possible.

I think, there is no way to do this, because list[int, int, int] doesn't exist. If you use list you can only specify data type which list contains, like list[int].
If you know that func1 returns a list of 3 integers, why don't make it return tuple of 3 integers?

Actually, in my specific case func1 is an array that I am pulling from a .toml file, which is converted to a Python list. Now if I convert the list to a tuple, then I can't annotate var1 as tuple[int, int, int] because new error will be thrown that says got tuple instead of tuple[int, int, int]. This is an issue as func2 expects tuple[int, int, int].
